# Guess the number game

Tags: python-2.7

Im getting a few errors not sure how to fix them i am very new to coding.
Would be really great to get some help thanks.

```
#Author : John Smith
#Date   : 3/19/17
#
#Guess the number game
#1 Player vs. Computer
import random
minGuess = 1
maxGuess =6

#Ask the user for their name and their guess
name = input("What is your name")
print("Hi + name")
print("Enter a number between: " +minGuess + " and " + maxGuess)
guess = int(input("what is your guess?"))

#Generate a random number and tell the user if they have won or lost
secretNumber = random.randint(minGuess, maxGuess)
if (guess != ??????)
    print("congratz you got it right")
else:
    print("You loose the number was ???")

print("Thankyou for playing guess the number.")
```

Comment: Include  errors you get while running it ..

Answer (score 0):

`print("Hi + name")`  should be  `print("Hi "+ name)` if you want to use the variable name from the line above.

I guess your error is coming from this line  `if (guess != ??????)`.  You need to change the "??????", (since it doesn't mean anything for Python) into something else. What do you think "guess" should be compared to ?

Answer (score 0):

it could be nice if you will write the errors you got.
the only problem i can see is `if(guess != ??????)`
the expression ?????? is undefined and also invalid in python as var name